# how to find the closest string for a given string with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, closest

let me make my question clear.
i have some pattern string like below in database,

```
0070m6nkfszczw8zzgswgzz8wzgz0

0070m6nkfszczw8zzgswgzz8wzgz3

0070m6nkfszczw8zzgswgzz8wzgza

0070m6nkfszczw8zzgswgzz8wzgzb

0070m6nkfszczw8zzgswgzz8wzgzc

0070m6nkfszczw8zzgswgzz8wzgzd

0070m6nkfszczw8zzgswgzz8wzgzf

0070m6nkfszczw8zzgswgzz8wzgzg
```

for a input string :

```
0070m6nkfszczw8zzgswgzz8wzgze
```

it is not in database, but i just want find the near record after insert it to database
the question is :
can i store the strings with order in database ?
how can i get the closest ones ?
for:`0070m6nkfszczw8zzgswgzz8wzgze`

the previous one is: 
`0070m6nkfszczw8zzgswgzz8wzgzd`

the next is: 
`0070m6nkfszczw8zzgswgzz8wzgzf`

thanks

Comment: What is your DBMS? What did you try?

Comment: Have a look at [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and see check if there's a function available in the database you're using.

Comment: sorry, dtabase is mysql

Comment: You're going to have to define "closest".  You _can_ trivially get next/previous entry, but these might not be close, depending on what you consider close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are thinking in alphabetic order. Then get then maximum value which is smaller or equal your value and the minimum value wich is bigger or equal your value.

```
select min(string)
from mytable
where string >= @mystring
union
select max(string)
from mytable
where string <= @mystring;
```

This will find the value you want to look up. If it doesn't exist, it will give you the neighbours if any. (If you don't want to get the exact match, then change `<=` to `<` and `>=` to `>` and `union` to `union all`.)